# Wait until IO Buffer is fully written in GoLang

Tags: go, buffer

I'm using a printer (ESC POS) that prints text when data is written on /dev/usb/lp0

The simplified code is:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    f, err := os.Create("/dev/usb/lp0")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)

    w.Write([]byte("\x1B@"))
    w.WriteString("test-1\n")
    w.WriteString("test-2\n")
    w.WriteString("test-3\n")
    w.WriteString("test-4\n")
    w.WriteString("test-5\n")
    w.WriteString("test-6\n")
    w.WriteString("test-7\n")
    w.WriteString("test-8\n")
    w.WriteString("test-9\n")

    w.Flush()
    f.Sync()
}
```

and most of the time the last line is not printed, unless I add a timer at the very end.

I think I closed everything properly, so not sure what's going on here... If I write to a file, it works fine BTW, luck ?

Thank you in advance, I spend last evening on this and it is driving me crazy :)

EDIT: Code with error handling (f.Sync() actually failed and I removed it)

```
    package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    f, err := os.Create("/dev/usb/lp0")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)

    _, err = w.Write([]byte("\x1B@"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-1\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-2\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-3\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-4\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-5\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-6\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-7\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-8\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.WriteString("toto-9\n")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = w.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is not printing. Because I have tried that code in windows and it is printing upto `test-9`. Are you getting any error. If so, Please post it here.

Comment: @Himanshu: How are you running that on Windows? `/dev` doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: yes @Flimzy, I have changed the path when creating a file. So basically I have written to a file.

Comment: I think that invalidates the test. I believe the OP's problem has to do with waiting for the attached lp0 device to flush its buffers before the program exits.

Comment: It's on Linux, on 2 machines, my laptop and a Raspberry Pi. The last line test-9 doesn't show, but on other scenarios it stops at any place "randomly". Writing to a "real" file works just fine

Comment: @Flimzy yes something like that, but in my original program it doesn't exit and it works if I add a 5s sleep before the end of the method

Comment: I would say that should not make any difference as the LP device should just block the writer. But in order to prove or disprove this please *add error handling* first. Any of the method calls on `w` may legitimately return non-`nil` error (and `f.Sync()`, too), and you're ignoring them all.

Comment: Start with something like https://play.golang.org/p/_cEyYCtGZZ3 to replace your `w.WriteString` calls. That's not something you should use in production but is okay for such PoC/debugging code.

Comment: I didn't put the error handling to keep it shorter but here is the code with it and shows no error

Comment: PS I added a few lines to print and it stops at the same place. If I move the code to a new func and add `time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)` at the end of the func then I get all the text, but if I call my func and then do the Sleep in the `main` then it stops printing after the test-8 without any error...

Comment: (No I was right...) When I compile with 1.7.4 it works, when I compile with 1.9.6 it fails... I will try 1.10 and try to figure out when it broke...

Comment: I can confirm, it works until version 1.8.7 and then fails on v1.9 v1.9.6 and v1.10.2 (I tried multiple times those versions).

Comment: I opened a bug report https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25631